# Pandas for 24 hour time series

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, time-series, tweepy

I'm tring to adapt the time series visualisation code [here](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/04/01/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-5-data-visualisation-basics/) so that instead of graphing frequency by date I want frequency plotted against time (ignoring date).

So I want to count over let's say 3 months, how many tweets were sent at 12AM, how many tweets were sent at 12:01AM, how many tweets were sent at 12:02AM etc.

I have tried the following:

```
dates_TweetText = []
for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob("*.txt")):
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    # track when the word is mentioned
    if s in preprocess(tweet['text']):
        import datetime, pytz
        thedate=datetime.datetime.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
        thetime=datetime.time(thedate.hour,thedate.minute)
        dates_TweetText.append(thetime)
# a list of "1" to count the hashtags
ones = [1]*len(dates_TweetText)
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(dates_TweetText)
```

which crashes on the last line with error `TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()`

The dates and times all look OK e.g. `2015-11-18 19:33:15+00:00  and 19:33:00`

Is this because Pandas requires dates and times won't work this way? Is there another way to do a 24 hour plot? TIA!!!

EDIT: Following EdChum's advice I've tried this:

```
dates_TweetText = []
for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob("*.txt")):
    print 'file', fileinput.filename(), line
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    # track when the word is mentioned
    if s in preprocess(tweet['text']):
        dates_TweetText.append(tweet['created_at'])

# a list of "1" to count the hashtags
print type(dates_TweetText)
ones = [1]*len(dates_TweetText)
# the index of the series
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(dates_TweetText)
```

which works but the 'resample' line below crashes, with error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex` when I try to use `idx.time` (runs OK without the .time but just gives a plot by date)

```
# the actual series (at series of 1s for the moment)
TweetText = pd.Series(ones, index=idx.time)
# Resampling / bucketing
return TweetText.resample('1Min', how='sum').fillna(0)
```

Comment: It's probably borking on the fact you're trying to use an array of `time` objects as the data arg for a `DatetimeIndex` could you not just keep it as `Datetime`? You can trim to just the date or time later using `.time` or `.date` of the index object

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but get another error as EDITed into the question.